# dialog html5 produces scrolling issue when it was closed

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, modal-dialog

In my page, I implemented modal dialogs via html5 tag `<dialog>` styled with CSS. This is my code to create the dialog:

```
function dialog(msj, tit, element){
    if (!tit) { var tit = "Mensaje" };
    if (!element) { var element = document.querySelector("section"); };
    var dlg = document.createElement("dialog");
    dlg.className = "msj";
    var h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    h2.innerHTML = tit;
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = msj;
    var ac = document.createElement("button");
    ac.innerHTML = "Aceptar";
    ac.className = "btn btn-form2";
    ac.onclick = function(){ dlg.close(); element.removeChild(dlg); sigDiag(); } //The button closes and removes the dialog from the element and show the next dialog (if exists)
    dlg.appendChild(h2);
    dlg.appendChild(p);
    dlg.appendChild(ac);
    dlg.oncancel = function() { element.removeChild(dlg); sigDiag(); } //same action that onclose but its fired when ESC key is pressed
    element.appendChild(dlg);
    if (document.querySelectorAll("dialog").length == 1) { //Shows the dialog if there are no more dialogs in the page
        dlg.showModal();
    }
}

function sigDiag() {
    var dlg = document.querySelector("dialog");
    if (dlg) { dlg.showModal(); }
}
```

All the content of the page is contained in a `<section>` tag. The rest of the page (menu items, logo and more) is contained in `<header>`, `<nav>` and `<footer>` tags respectively. The button that fires the dialog function is in a div styled with overflow:auto with fixed height.

When dialog has been closed (with button or ESC key), the div don't scroll with the mouse wheel but the arrow keys scrolls normally.

Is there anyway to fix this issue in Chrome? Version 47.0.2526.106 (Build oficial) m (32 bits)

PD: Its my first question in StackOverflow, sorry for my bad English. It's not my native language and I accept suggestions...

**UPDATE:**

The code is in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eajwvLow/

The result of this in full window (the most important): https://fiddle.jshell.net/eajwvLow/show/

"Iframed" result in the jsfiddle's code window doesn't reflect the actual behavior of the button (my situation).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to make the code readable. One line functions are not nice to read and take a couple looks to understand sometimes. Thanks

Comment: Reproducing on https://jsfiddle.net/ will make it easier for us to help you.